# Removing underline from image

Tags: .net, html, css, visual-studio-2010, hyperlink

Purple line around the image:

I have following html code:

```
<a id="a1" href="test.aspx" target="_blank">
        <img id="Img2" src="Images/Icon.gif" runat="server" style="width: 70px;  text-align: center;" />
</a>
```

The image which I get here has a purple border around it. Like the color of visited hyperlinks.

I tried adding styles: Text-decoration: none. 
Tried - white border and tried setting style to none for all: a link, a visited

But still the purple border remains. Any help ? I dont want any border around my image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably not a border of the image, but of the link.

You could do the following:

```
<a id="a1" style="border:0;" href="test.aspx" target="_blank">
    <img id="Img2" src="Images/Icon.gif" runat="server" style="width: 70px;  text-align: center;border:0;" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens when I use IE (6, 7, 8) to solve it added to my stylesheet:

```
img {
     border: none;
}
```

I hope will be helpful.